# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS - IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, https, iis-7.5

I have implemented https on my application and now i'm trying to make IIS redirect all http request to https, so that the user doesn't even notice this change.

I have changed and tried some of the IIS options but with no luck.

How can i do this?

I'm using IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET 2.0

Regards,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can install the [RewriteModule](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) and follow the instructions on [this page](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/redirect_http_to_https_iis_7).

Comment: Is it really necessary to install an extension?

Comment: No, but this is the easiest way. [Here](http://raoulpop.com/2007/08/07/automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https/) some other options.

Comment: [This](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/three_methods_redirect_http_https) may also be helpful.

Comment: Where exactly on my web.config should i add the <rules> tag?

Comment: In `<system.webServer> <rewrite> <rules>` but you can use IIS manager to create the rule.

Comment: I'm pleased to help you. Do you know about the principle of accepting answers here by clicking on the checkbox outline beside your favorite answer?

Answer (score 17):

The approach described in this [blog article](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/11/how-to-redirect-sites-to-https-in-iis-7-5/) works well.

**Summary:**
1) Turn on "Require SSL" setting for the site.
[image: SSL Settings]

2) In the Error settings configuration for 403 errors set it to "respond with 302 redirect" with the new URL set to the full URL with the https:// prefix.
[image: Change Error Page]
[image: Set Redirect Properties]

Comment: This is a pretty nice easy eay to do it. Do you know if this has any implication on SEO or page ranking? Does the 403 get thrown before the 302 or does IIS translate it before returning it?

Answer (score 3):

you can make a simple check on the global.asax, on beginRequest, something like this code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

        if(!app.Response.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            app.Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace("http://","https://"), true);
            return;
        }
    }
```

ps. I did not have check this code, I just type it now.

Comment: +1 Here is a sample that we currently use:
    `void global_asax_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        if (!app.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https"))
        {
            app.Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"), true);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else runs into a http:// site that will not redirect. You also have to have the port 80 binding added to the site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in IIS 7**

URL Rewrite is tightly integrated with IIS Manager for better management(Download from https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9722532)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAGGj.png)

**Configure Rule Settings**

*Match URL tab*:
 name= Redirect 2 HTTPS 
 url= (.*)

*Conditions tab*: add record
    input= {HTTPS} 
    pattern= ^OFF$

*Action tab*: 
    type= Redirect 
    redirection URL= https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1} 
 
    redirectType= Permanent