# How to redirect from http to https in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, http, https, redirect, angular5

I built an Angular 5 project. It works fine when I write the URL https://www.example.com/, but when I simply write [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or http://example.com in the browser it won't redirect. Is there a file where I can make the URL always redirect to https://www.example.com? I'm using a Windows server and it runs IIS. Thank you!

Comment: Use rewrite module: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/22/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS - IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369746/redirect-from-http-to-https-iis-7-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure this in your IIS (Internet Information Service) configuration and not inside your Angular code, since it is a URL rewrite and not a duplication of the Website.

Either you configure it with an web.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you don't know how to use IIS configuration files i can recommend you to read the [Microsoft documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617(v=ws.10).aspx).

Or you could use a Tool like described in [this Microsoft Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/22/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher/) (Maybe a little bit easier, because it has a GUI, however you will have to reconfigure it each time you move to a different server):

Comment: "Either you configure it with an web.config file:" Do you mean "OR you configure it with an web.config file:"?