# How to redirect http to https and index.html together on IIS in React single page application?

Tags: http, iis, https

We have a single page application, made in React JS and deployed on IIS. HTTPS certificate is already setup on the server and our application runs all fine on HTTPS. I want to redirect all calls from HTTP to HTTPS. Here is how my web.config file looks like on the server. Can you please help me with what rule should I add in it and where to transfer my HTTP calls to HTTPS?

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>                     
            <rule name="rewrite index to index.html">
                 <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
                 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/ABC/api/*" negate="true" />
                 </conditions>
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule> 

        </rules>            
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/html" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS - IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369746/redirect-from-http-to-https-iis-7-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer to my question.. Here it is

```
<rule name="Redirect everything to https://example.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```